# compare two data.tables by row and add new column

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables that I want to each row compare and add new column.

```
DT1 <- data.table(ID=c("F","A","E","B","C","D","C"),
                  num=c(59,3,108,11,22,54,241),
                  value=c(90,47,189,72,42,86,280))

DT2 <- data.table(Mark=c("Mary","Abner","Bonnie","Trista","Norman"),
                  numA=c(48,20,88,237,10),
                  numB=c(60,326,54,268,89),
                  valueA=c(78,34,78,270,60),
                  valueB=c(92,190,90,385,75))
```

My goal:

I want to find num and value in DT1, and there is a range of numA and numB in DT2.

For example:

For row F num = 59 and value = 90 in DT1, must also match:

num(59) > DT2$numA(48) & num(59) < DT2$numB(60) & value(90) > DT2$valueA(78) & value(90) < DT2$valueB(92)

match! so add new column name result, and value is Mark by dt2

If there is no match, set it to Undefined

Desired result:

```
DT3 <- data.table(ID=c("F","A","E","B","C","D","C"),
              num=c(59,3,108,11,22,54,241),
              value=c(90,47,189,38,42,86,280),
              result=c("Mary","Undefined","Abner","Norman",
                       "Abner","Abner","Trista"))
```

How to ensure that each row has a comparison and add a new column?

Comment: How do you resolve conflicts?  When there are more than one match which one do you take? Currently, I am taking the first match.

Comment: I have thought about this problem, but for my original data, it seems to be fine, as long as you can find the corresponding information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A data.table option:

```
DT1[DT2, on=.(num > numA, num < numB, value > valueA, value < valueB), Mark := i.Mark]

 DT1
   ID num value   Mark
1:  F  59    90  Abner
2:  A   3    47   <NA>
3:  E 108   189  Abner
4:  B  11    72 Norman
5:  C  22    42  Abner
6:  D  54    86  Abner
7:  C 241   280 Trista
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use :=, but there is no success, your method can, I have to study data.table again.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this could be solved more efficiently using one of join operation in `data.table`, however, here is one base R option using `mapply`

```
DT1$result <- mapply(function(x, y) {
   inds <- x > DT2$numA & x < DT2$numB & y > DT2$valueA & x < DT2$valueB
   if(any(inds))
     DT2$Mark[which.max(inds)]
   else "Undefined"
}, DT1$num, DT1$value)


DT1
#   ID num value    result
#1:  F  59    90      Mary
#2:  A   3    47 Undefined
#3:  E 108   189     Abner
#4:  B  11    72    Norman
#5:  C  22    42     Abner
#6:  D  54    86      Mary
#7:  C 241   280    Trista
```